# Is having a high school diploma a requirement to taking the PPM exam?

Tags: certification

Is it a requirement to have a high school diploma in order to take the PPM exam? I have been doing project management for the past 5 years.

Comment: You do realize that nothing said in this forum is binding on PMI?  It really would make more sense to contact PMI with questions about PMI rules.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say without knowing which PPM exam.
[APMG offers a PPM exam](http://www.apmg-international.com/en/qualifications/ppm-certificate-diploma/ppm-certification-diploma.aspx)
[SPSU offers a PPM exam](http://www.spsu.edu/cec/courses/qm/ProfProjMgmtCert.htm)
[CA offers a PPM exam](http://www.ca.com/us/education/accreditations/certification-for-ca-clarity-ppm.aspx)
Some people refer to the [PfMP](http://www.pmi.org/en/Certification/Portfolio-Management-Professional-PfMP.aspx) certification as the [PPM](http://pmzilla.com/whats-difference-betweem-pmp-and-ppm)

This is one of the reasons I strongly prefer to provide URL/links for terms in the question that are not common.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean PMP, the answer would be yes.  It has two criteria, one for high school graduates and the other for college graduates.  There is no third criterion for ones without high school diploma.